# How To Count and Group By Same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I am trying to get a result like below, column names don't matter I can edit them later on.

```
Date - Visit Amount- Customer Count by Visit Amount 
2020        1                  10                   
2020        2                  50                   
2020        3                  123                  
2020        6                  24
```

I have date and customer_id columns. In a nutshell, I am trying to find in 2020 how many customers visited my shop 1 time, 2 times etc. I am not able to find it cuz can't group by visit amounts.

Comment: Please show the data in your table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to find in 2020 how many customers visited my shop 1 time, 2 times etc.

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_visits, count(*) as num_customers
from (select customer_id, count(*) as num_visits
      from visits v
      where visit_dt >= '2020-01-01' and visit_dt < '2021-01-01'
      group by customer_id
     ) v
group by num_visits
order by num_visits;
```

This makes up table and column names, because your question doesn't provide them.  But it should be easy to see what it is doing.

EDIT:

If you want each year separately:

```
select year, num_visits, count(*) as num_customers
from (select year(visit_dt) as year, customer_id, count(*) as num_visits
      from visits v
      group by year(visit_dt), customer_id
     ) v
group by year, num_visits
order by year, num_visits desc;
```

Comment: The names you used are ok, I changed them, thanks a lot for the help. How can I show dates as the first column?

`Date - Visit Amount- Customer Count by Visit Amount 
2020          1                       10                   
2020          2                       50                   
2020          3                       123                  
2020          6                       24  
2019          1                       18
2019          2                       24`

Comment: Basically, instead of checking specific dates, can I see all the data by years in the same format like date, num_visits, count?

Comment: @Anil . . . That is a minor tweak to the query, so I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE.

```
WITH TBL AS (
    --your first grouping query here
),
AS TBL2 (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(Visit_Amount) Visit_Amount,
        COUNT(Customer_Count_by_Visit_Amount) Customer_Count_by_Visit_Amount
    FROM TBL 
    GROUP BY Visit_Amount,Customer_Count_by_Visit_Amount
)
SELECT * FROM TBL2
```